# How to create a Connectable Web Part on sharePoint

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-foundation, data-view-web-part

Is it possible to create a custom connectable web part that passes information to a DataView out-of-the-box SharePoint webpart?

I'm not interested in creating a consumer and provider web part as I saw some examples in the web, like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms469765%28office.14%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for a filter provider web part, which basically provides filtering values to other web parts capable of consuming those filters.

In such case you would need to implement the ITransformableFilterValues interface, you should be aware that, to my knowledge out-of-the-box ListView web parts only accept 1 value, such as multi-valued (e.g. multi-choice columns like) cannot work.

For an exact example have a look at this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/edhild/archive/2007/03/28/how-to-build-a-custom-filter-provider-web-part.aspx or this series of articles http://bilbrobloggins.com/sharepoint/dropdown-list-box-filter-web-part-in-sharepoint-ndash-part-three/ or http://akurniaga.wordpress.com/tag/itransformablefiltervalues/

Answer (score 0):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/sharepointdevelopment/thread/53245214-CAE8-4A3F-96D1-BFB321FB1339

Comment: While this post may answer the question, we prefer more details such as "why". Please edit your post with additional details. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.

Comment: It does actually not give a solution to my problem. I need to create an **custom** webpart that is able to connect to a out-of-the-box SharePoint webpart.

Comment: So why you don't interesting in creating consumer and provider? This is the way to connect to OOB webpart!

Comment: Because I would like to use the data on my custom webpart to filter the information on the SharePoint Webpart (showing a list). So I don't need to send information between my own webparts, but between my custom webpart an a out-of-the-box one.

Comment: OOB webpart already contains consumer, so you should realize provider to filter values in OOB webpart!

Comment: But there is one limitation: OOB web part can get only one filter value!

Answer (score 0):

You can create query string parameters and use them to drive filters in your OOB list view.  Your custom web parts just needs to post back to itself using the query string values.  A common scenario is a web part where users select a parent list item in a drop down, then the child list items are displayed according to the parent item selected in the drop down.

You can use multiple query string values and multiple filters using this approach.